# Tamaño de apk al instalarla en dispositivo

Tags: android

Amigos tengo un problema, el detalle está cuando genero mi apk esta viene pesando alrededor de 6 MB, hasta ahí todo bien, al momento de instalarla en dispositivos el tamaño de ella se extiende considerablemente ya instalada logra ocupar 18 MB de espacio en otros 36MB y otros 8MB, mi duda es ¿A que se deberá? Por que no mantiene un tamaño fijo en todos los dispositivos al momento de ser instalada? ya que no contiene mucho código y recursos.

Comment: Al instalar el sistema adapta la aplicación considerando las distintas características de los dispositivos, por ejemplo, los recursos para un dispositivo con una pantalla de alta densidad son más pesados que los de un dispositivo con pantalla de menor resolución. Además, el sistema crea una copia del APK.

Comment: Al instalarse una aplicación en un dispositivo se crea una copia del `apk` en `/data/app`, una versión [DVM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik) compilada y "optimizada" en `/data/dalvik-cache` con extensión `odex` (optimized dex) o en versiones modernas de Android se usa [ART](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime_%28ART%29), las librerías, etc. Todo esto hace que el tamaño dependa de la versión de Android y de la versión "optimizada" en particular de cada plataforma. No puedes tener control sobre esto, depende de cada dispositivo en particular.

Comment: Gracias @lois6b .. me has convencido :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia nada. lo unico que sigo pensando en si esta pregunta pertenece o no... de momento no tiene votos de cierre pero si un negativo...

Comment: Creo que la duda es legítima y muchos nos la hemos hecho en algún momento. Yo he tenido dispositivos con memoria interna muy reducida, por lo que hubo un tiempo que investigué sobre ese tema y me pareció raro que se desperdiciara tanto espacio. Lo que sí es cierto que el tema de las librerías vuelve loco, aún no entiendo muy bien como funcionan en cuanto a espacio. Aunque he desarrollado varias aplicaciones opencv, dependiendo de cada dispositivo el tamaño de mi aplicación varía sustancialmente, nunca he tenido un resultado consistente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia yo antes media muy mucho las aplicaciones que podia tener y no tener (memoria interna pequeña y slot de SD estropeado. Ahora con 128gb de interna instalo a lo loco xDDD

Comment: para optimizar el tamaño, es buena practica optimizar las librerias, por ejemplo no usar compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.1.0 y **especificar** dentro del grupo de apis,  que ofrece google

Comment: "Al instalarse una aplicación en un dispositivo se crea una copia del apk en /data/app, una versión DVM compilada y "optimizada" en /data/dalvik-cache con extensión odex (optimized dex) o en versiones modernas de Android se usa ART, las librerías, etc." **Esto no provoca nunca la variación considerable de MB al instalar la aplicación!** 18 MB - 36MB - 8MB  . =|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tamaño que tendrá una aplicación al instalarse en un dispositivo depende de varios factores.

Al instalarse la aplicación se crea una copia del `apk` en `/data/app`.

Posteriormente se genera una versión [DVM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik) compilada y "optimizada" en `/data/dalvik-cache` con extensión `odex` (optimized dex) o en versiones modernas de Android se usa [ART](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime_%28ART%29), librerías etc.

El tamaño del archivo optimizado que genera la versión DVM y ART dependen de la versión de Android, la plataforma hardware (ARM, x86, x86_64, etc), etc, por lo que no puedes tener control sobre esto ni calcularlo de una única manera.

Comment: Perfecto me ha quedado claro ya que no se encuentra mucha info detalladamente como esta gracias :D

Comment: Me faltó decir que el archivo `odex` se genera a partir del archivo `dex` que hay dentro del `apk`, que al descomprimirse (un `apk` es simplemente un archivo `zip` con una estructura de archivos preestablecida) podría ser en algunos casos incluso mayor que el `apk` original... pero eso suele pasar en pocas ocasiones.

Comment: Esto no podría provocar una variación de espacio en MB de 18 MB - 36MB - 8MB como lo comenta el OP

Answer (score 1):

El .apk puede variar de tamaño al ser instalado en un dispositivo por dos razones princiales:

> - Toma en cuenta que es un archivo comprimido ( puedes comprobarlo al cambiar la extensión de .apk a .zip), cuando es instalado aumenta
>     obviamente el espacio requerido.
> - Tu aplicación puede generar una datos en cache, base de datos o preferencias que dependiendo de la información el tamaño puede
>     aumentar, por ejemplo una aplicación puede tener más datos en un
>     dispositivo porque un usuario reviso todas las secciones y por lo
>     tanto descargo a cache más datos, por ejemplo imágenes.

---

En cuanto a la optimización de código para reducir el tamaño es buena opción usar [Proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) o [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard) (aunque existen otras opciones).

Para reducir el tamaño, tal vez hayas visto dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` la propiedad:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Te recomiendo leas este artículo:

[Reducir tu código y tus recursos](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html?hl=es-419)